# Three js, ammo js and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, three.js, ammo.js

I'm starting with ammo js and I've effectively loaded a three js scene with ammo js. Now what's happening is that when I load the page it works but when a change to a new page(another html) and go back to the page that has the scene, it gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Ammo is not a function

Know since I'm using ruby on rails, I implemented the ammo.js library in the application.js file.

The below text is an example of what I'm using.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 start(){
  //three js and ammo js code
 }
 $('document').ready(function(){
         
   Ammo().then(start)

 })
```

EDIT: ammo.js version 4.0.3,
Three js version r120
application.js has:

```
//= require three
//= require OrbitControls
//= require THREE.MeshLine
//= require ammo
//= require physi
//= require STLExporter
```

Comment: Provide more information like versions and code. I.e. app/assets/application.js and the application.html.erb, etc.

Comment: Also specify rails version and method of assets management. Using turbolinks, jquery, webpack, etc?

Comment: This error may be because the library is not loaded. Check Rails logs to see that the asset is actually served by Rails and then loaded in the browser in the Sources tab of Chrome or any debugging tool which can show the sources.